# All Rails urls are returning error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a Rails app that is running on a development VPS Ubuntu server with Apache and Phusion Passenger. I've developed app on local machine, where app is working flawless. I deployed app, run all the bundle installs, I am runing the same gem, rails, rvm and rake versions as local machine and I've successfuly migrated database (SQLite).

But on my VPS, which is also runing on the development enviroment, ALL of the routes are returning 500 error. I Googled for two days now and I cannot get it up and runing. 
My development log is returning ONLY one line which is:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

This is my database.yml which is set correcty, also db/development.sqlite3 is present on VPS server.

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I am desperate what to do now. I have sqlite installed, all the same gems as local machine,.. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the error log on apache ?

Comment: I am using nginx. Which error log file should I use? Thank you.

Comment: did you use nginx to proxy to the rails app or just access the rails directly ? 

if you use nginx then there should be an error log. on the nginx site configuration there should be line like `error_log /path/to/file` http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: check the log file in your app and see what is getting written to. You're mostly likely in production mode and not development.

Comment: @ahmy : I used nginx. I have set error_log logs/error.log debug; and I am looking at /opt/nginx/logs but all files are from yesterday - I've tried accesing the app right now, but no log is created. (i restarted nginx after changing error_log.

timpone: I think I am in the development mode, because only development log file is being created. It says: Connecting to database specified by database.yml

Comment: Ok, some more info. @timpone i've found the error log now. 

http://pastebin.com/N2wJEbKc

I can see error that table doctors is missing. I've loaded schema, but still no luck.

Comment: sometimes adding the host option to the database.yml helps fix some errors. It might be localhost but depends on your VPS

Comment: Have you migrated the database in development mode? You should be running in production mode NOT dev mode on your server. Also are your assets compiled? Capistrano should be handling all this for you. Are your deployment scripts OK and lastly can you ssh into your server and run a rails console session?

Comment: @jamesw Yes, I am runing production mode on server now. rake assets:precompile is done, still no luck.
And yes, I can run console via SSH.

Comment: You using unicorn? Could be a sockets problem

Comment: If the sockets don't match on the nginx config and the unicorn config then nginx will return 500 error before it even gets to your rails site

Answer (score 1):

have you compiled your assets?

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments then I would guess that this is an issue with your nginx configuration as you are able to run a rails console.

Assuming you are using unicorn with nginx Make sure that the nginx and unicorn sockets match

i.e.
in the nginx.conf upstream section

```
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mobile.sock
```

Matches unicorn.rb listening socket

```
listen "/tmp/unicorn.mobile.sock"
```

Obviously replace the socket names/paths to appropriate settings for your server but if the sockets are not the same nginx will never be able to talk to unicorn, and your rails app will never be launched and nginx will return a 500 error.